# How much force needs to be applied to get a body to a new position time?

Tags: physics

I have a physics body with a mass m and existing non zero linear velocity v and position p.  How much force needs to be applied to get it to a new position pn in t seconds?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/ more relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ever useful kinematics equation:
$$d = v_0t + \frac12at^2$$
Can be used to find the neccesary acceleration. Then Newton's second law:
$$F = ma$$
Can be used to find force.

Comment: So I'm using F = m2(d-vot)/t^2 but the results are off by one or two orders of magnitude for some reason.  This led me to believe that I'd got some mismatched units but they are all in meters, seconds, kilograms, any thoughts?